# Baby wet the bed (almost 2 years old)

Tags: toddler, sleep, potty-training, bedtime, bed-wetting

i'm new over here. also i'm new in parenting in genenral - this is my first son :)
hopefully that i'm not duplicating [this question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14803/potty-trained-2-1-2-year-old-wetting-the-bed-again), my 20 month baby is wetting the bed every single night, we haven't started with potty training and we always change the clothes and diaper as answered the [answered question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14803/potty-trained-2-1-2-year-old-wetting-the-bed-again) suggested, but it never stops! 
he awake in the middle of the night for water so we make sure that he'll have a bottle with a little bit of water next to him while he sleeps. 
also we giving him baby formula to sleep with but we cut the amounts because he's eating quite nicely at dinner.

my question is how to help him stop wetting the bed?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Is your son wearing a diaper to bed? If so, have you tried switching to a more absorbent diaper? I'm not sure I understand your general concern.

Comment: thank you :)
yes, he is wearing a diaper, and we did! actually it was the first thing we did.
i understand the confusion, my question is how can we help him to stop wetting the bed?

Comment: Hello, my daughter is almost 3 years old and still wearing diaper at night (not at daytime). My son is almost 5 and stopped wearing diaper at night a few month ago (so a little bit more than 4 and a half). I think this is normal.

Comment: thank you @Mackie, it's reassuring :)

Comment: @comand: If you find my comment helpful, could you please give it an upvote? Thank you :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While doing all the laundry is annoying, night time [bed-wetting is considered normal in children under 5](https://patient.info/childrens-health/bedwetting-nocturnal-enuresis#:%7E:text=Bedwetting%20is%20still%20considered%20normal%20in%20children%20under%20the%20age%20of%205%20years.). Its common for (day time) potty trained children to not be dry at night even for quite a while after getting the idea in the day. One reason is the [hormone vasopressin needs to be produced to help slow down the production of urine in the night](https://www.urologyhealth.org/urologic-conditions/bed-wetting-(enuresis)), so you may just be waiting until this kicks in.

You can do things to help, make sure your child is drinking plenty in the day, maybe limit fluid intake for an hour before bed, make sure they have a chance to potty before bed, and night-time nappies/diapers which fit (to save you the laundry!)

Answer (score 0):

He's too young to go 11 hours without urinating.  Just put him in a diaper or pull up at night until his body is ready.

Some kids still wet the bed at eight at age 8 or so.  It's just because brain and bladder aren't communicating, and there's nothing you can do to make that happen any faster.

Comment: If you look at the comments, you'll see that the baby *is* wearing a diaper to bed. I believe the OP is dealing with "overflow", if you will. Also, by the age of 8, therapies for enuresis are available and fairly effective.